# Examples of solvable set equations. ( References on this topic?)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I recently asked a question concerning set equations and a possible mechanical method to solve them.

If I am correct ( and after having read the answer given) there isn't such a method.

I conclude from this that set equations are in general not solvable.

I can find however some examples of solvable ones. For example :

(X Union A) = U     ( With U = the universal set)

which, I think, can be solved in this way

X Union A = U

<-> (X Union A) Inter A' = U Inter A'

<-> (X inter A') Union (A Inter A') = U Inter A'

<-> (X Inter A') Union Empty set =  A'

<-> X Inter A' = A'

<-> X = U or X = A'

Could anyone give more examples ( or, possibly, a reference in which I could find 
some exercice on the topic of set equation)?

Comment: From $X\cap U = U$ you cannot conclude $X=U,$ only that $U\subseteq X$

Comment: @saulspatz. Thanks, you're right. I haowever cannot understand how I can both have  (1) X Inter U is equal to X  and (2) X Inter U = U does not imply X=U...

Comment: If you have $X\cap U=X$ and $X\cap U=U$ then of course, $X=U.$  Equality is an equivalence relation.  It will be easier to read your posts if you learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @saulspatz. Thanks for the link to MathJax.